Diactric sign ó not visible
Since a few months ago, in certain applications (eg. Mendeley) or some Internet websites (e.g. facebook), I cannot see sign ó. Instead, I see y.
I am able to type ó. If I type ó and see y instead, and then I copy it to another application, I see ó correctly. So it seems to be a visualization issue and not a keyboard one.
Almost all applications or web pages work well for me. Examples are LibreOffice, askubuntu.com.
My keyboard layout is Polish. The way I make Polish signs (óńłąę etc.) is by pressing simultaneously right-alt and the corresponding key, for ó it is right-alt and o keys.
Thanks for help!

How are you trying to generate this ó character? Using Ubuntu using the compose key (as set in your instance) followed by o then ' should work perfectly well. [edit] your question accordingly including which keyboard layout/language you have set.

I provided more information in the question. I have also turned on the compose key for a moment. I typed compose key followed by o and ',and it gave me y in Mendeley app, and ó in LibreOffice, so the same result as with right-alt.

then the issue is clearly with Mendeley which is not supported on Ask Ubuntu. Search for their help site resources instead.

And the Facebook page, and some other pages? Don't they support Ubuntu? Mendeley is just an example showing that this problem is not limited to web pages.
